# Confirm action then delete row from mysql table

Tags: javascript, php

I am using javascript to alert user if he is sure to delete row from database.
In html table I am using column for deleting rows.

```
<td><center><a href="" id="brisi" value="<?=$r['Id']; ?>" class="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure that you want to delete?"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></center>
```

I am using script to alert user then to navigate to php script to delete row

```
<script>
var deleteLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');

for (var i = 0; i < deleteLinks.length; i++) {
  deleteLinks[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var choice = confirm(this.getAttribute('data-confirm'));

      if (choice==true) {

         var x =document.getElementById("brisi").value;

            $.ajax({ url: 'edit/delete.php?a=1',
             type: 'post',
             success: function(output) {
             document.getElementById("brisi").value = output;

              }
        });
      }
      if (choice==false) {
        return false;
      }
  });
}
</script>
```

Php script

```
<?php

    if ($_GET['a']==1) {

        $id = test_input($_POST['brisi']);

        echo $id; 

    }

?>
```

I am trying to send value of each row. For some reason my js does not work, could anyone provide quick advice?

Comment: Why are you using `window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
` ?

Comment: you can use id instead of class to get individual row data.

Comment: *"For some reason my js does not work"* - A question like this should typically include a description of what actually happens and what you actually expect to happen, including error messages that the script console may give you.

Comment: This can easily  be done with ajax only, I don't like the combination of javascript and jquery. This combination makes the readability difficult

Answer (score 0):

you should change your html

```
<td><center><a href="javascript:;" data-value="<?=$r['Id']; ?>" class="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure that you want to delete?"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></center>
```

and also change javascript

```
$('.delete').off('click').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var choice = confirm($(this).data('confirm'));

    if(choice){
        var x = $(this).data('value');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'edit/delete.php?a=' + x,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(output) {
                document.getElementById("brisi").value = output;
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

and php code

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['a']) && $_GET['a'] != ''){
        $id = test_input($_GET['a']);
        echo $id;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');"

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know why you are checking for this:

```
var x =document.getElementById("brisi").value;
```

And you don't use it.

I hope also that 'brisi' is the unique ID only for this element.

Next you are doing a POST request with ajax:

```
        $.ajax({ url: 'edit/delete.php?a=1',
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
         document.getElementById("brisi").value = output;

          }
    });
```

I notice in your PHP you are trying to GET your posted vriable:

```
if ($_GET['a']==1) {

        $id = test_input($_POST['brisi']);

        echo $id; 

    }
```

And you should do:

```
if (isset($_POST['a') && $_POST['a'] == 1) {

            $id = test_input($_POST['brisi']);

            echo $id; 

        }
```

And finally what is this function doing:

```
test_input($_POST['brisi'])
```

You don't have any posted value with this index.

To recap If you need more help please post your complete HTML form.